# Google Actions permission access

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I have created a project on Google Actions. I would like to share the action with my friend. I tried giving them Viewer and Role Viewer access but they are not able to access the action on their mobile's Google Assistant App.

Could you tell me which Role shall I give it to them so that they can access my actions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should choose "Project / Viewer" as role.

Comment: After they are added as a viewer, they still need to go to the Actions console and enable testing for their account.

Comment: Ohh! What if they are non-developers? Just a normal user..Any other option?

Answer (score 0):

Go to project console settings in google actions console and add Basic/Viewer permission to user. It will able to test the action in google assistant app or simulator

Answer (score -1):

Once you have given them viewer access from your owner account, the Google Project will now be visible on their Actions console. Going in they will have to toggle the test status to ON, so that they can invoke the action from their mobile devices. I don't think there is a easier way around this.