# Could not access to the actions console of our project

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assist-api

We have several action console projects. But recently I could not access to one of our action console projects.
Normally I will access from list in here:
https://www.screencast.com/t/CWlbqhRFc
But now it always show error when I click to one of our projects in there.
https://www.screencast.com/t/b6DmCIcmDsec

I contact with google and ask them for helping. They said that it is caching problems and ask me clear cache on browser. I did it but error still happen. Many other members of this projects also got that error (We shared account of project with some members).

Does someone know the reason of this bug and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Roles you have for the project. You need to give Viewer Role to all the members of the project who are getting this error.

Please have a look into this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49276144/google-actions-permission-access) as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are a high chance there are a problem in google server. Because after we add a new device model. We could access our project again.